# why does _.delay turn my e.type from mouseenter to mouseover

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mouseevent, mouseover, underscore.js

When I trigger this event with backbone.js and I try and delay the function call the event.type is changed from mouseenter to mouseover    the console log shoots out "mouseenter" and the second log is "mouseover"   why the conversion???

```
app.newsroomPageElementView = Backbone.View.extend({
 events: {
    'mouseenter .featured-image': 'imageHover',
    'mouseleave .featured-image': 'imageHover'
 },
imageHover: function (e)  {
         Y.log(e.type); // this outputs out mouseenter
        _.delay(function(){ 
         Y.log(e.type); // this outputs mouseover
        }, 500);
    },    
});
```

is it because 500 miliseconds later my mouse has already "entered" so it actually is a mouseover, because my mouse is over the event when its triggered?

Comment: Try explicitly passing the `e` object: `_.delay(function (e) { ... }, 500, e);`

Comment: Also, try `setTimeout` instead of `_.delay` to check if this behavior is caused by `_.delay` (although I don't see how it could be).

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because Backbone is handing you a reference to an object that it then reuses.

As you probably know, the `mouseenter` event is followed by a `mouseover` event. You don't have a handler for `mouseover`, so normally, you wouldn't care.

When a `mouseenter` event occurs, your handler is called with this object `e`. This is a reference to some object within Backbone; you log its `type`, but then you retain a reference to that object in your `delay` handler.

Then, your event handler returns, and control is given back to the Javascript thread. The `mouseover` event fires. Your code may ignore it, but Backbone goes ahead and reuses the object it handed you and puts the information about the `mouseover` event in to it.

Then, your delay expires, and you use `e` to find out the type of the event... now its got all the `mouseover` event data in it, so that's what you see.

This should be a salutary lesson to us all. First, be aware that JS deals in object references and, if you store an object that something other than your code has created, and then break the thread, that object can change underneath you.
Equally, if you have methods that return arrays or objects, know that your are returning a reference to that array or object... thus, if calling code changes the contents of said array or object, this can mess you up; this is particularly dangerous when you have a private field with a public getter. If you're not careful, you can hand over a reference that allows code to change your objects internals, without you meaning to!

Comment: ["The `mouseenter` JavaScript event is proprietary to Internet Explorer. Because of the event's general utility, jQuery simulates this event so that it can be used regardless of browser."](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/). I suspect that this re-use of a single event object is specific to the simulated `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. Tagging the `e` with an extra property offers some hints: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/J2MFd/

Comment: So what is the final verdict?  is this function going to have problems that i need to worry about? I mean the examples from microsoft's site show certain mouseenter events being way less than the mouseovers, but since this function won't be called by backbone until mouseenter technically, if the event changes it shouldn't matter right? it should still only be triggered on that initial mouseenter and the delay will only happen after a successful mouseenter which requires me to have a mouseleave before it will refire.??

Comment: @ZurielAndrusyshyn: You can always clone `e` to avoid the reference problem.

Comment: @ZurielAndrusyshyn: you're right that the delay is only going to happen after a `mouseenter` (or `mouseleave`). As mu says, if you need to access the event data, you can clone `e` when it first comes in. However, Backbone and Loadash are not doing anything weird with events here, so you're OK.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zuriel/HRPDB/  updated the fiddle with both examples from mu and from api jquery website